# Why Netbeans 8.0 is not showing Source code

Tags: java, netbeans

Okay so the source tab on Netbeans 8.0 shows up on my school computers but not my personal tablet computer. I am frustrated beyond reason because i have no idea how to get my source tabe to appear on my personal computer. Any help beyond uninstalling and reinstalling would be much appreciated as i have tried to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Looks like you haven't attached the sources of your library (not even the own Java SE sources).

Comment: and how would one go about doing that?

Comment: @SeleneNox-See `Ian Fairman`'s answer.It'll work out for you!

Answer (score 2):

Try Ctrl-0 or from the menu "Window"/"Editor".

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is a corrupted userdir. Close NetBeans, remove your userdir, and reopen NetBeans. It will recreate the userdir, and you should have your source tab back. See below, copied from http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

**NetBeans 7.2 and newer**

The default location of the userdir is specific to the given system.
By default on Windows and Mac OS X the userdir is inside a directory NetBeans in application settings folder (usually at C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ on Windows 7, and at /Users//Library/Application Support/ on Mac OS X).

On Unix-like systems the userdir is inside a (hidden) directory called .netbeans in the user's home directory. The home directory path is ${HOME}.
On Windows XP system userdir is localised to your language, so in english version it is in: c:\Documents and Settings\Your Name\Application Data\NetBeans\7.3\

As the name suggests, the userdir is unique per user. For each version of NetBeans installed, the userdir will be a unique subdirectory such as NetBeans/.

To find out your exact userdir location, go to the IDE's main menu, and choose Help > About. (Mac: NetBeans > About NetBeans).

Answer (score 0):

Window / Reset Windows could be an option

[image]